# Using Ajax with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to fetch information from a database with AJAX with html buttons, without having to refresh the browser.

I can make it work via HTML with the code below, but I want to do it via Ajax.

I have the following code in the same file, example.html;

```
<form action="?" method="get">
    <input id="Button1" type="hidden" name="q" value="%U/%Y"/>
    <input id="Button1" style="width: auto" type="button" value="Weekly stats">
</form>

<form action="?" method="get">
    <input id="Button2" type="hidden" name="q" value="%M/%Y"/>
    <input id="Button2" style="width: auto" type="submit" value="Monthly Stats">
</form>

<br>

<?php 

//execute a mysql query to retrieve all the users from users table
//if  query  fails stop further execution and show mysql error
if ($_GET['q'] == '') {
    $q = '%M/%Y';
}
else {
    $q = $_GET['q'] ;
}  
$query=mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((post_date), '".$q."') 'Date',
                    SUM(balance) 'Balance'
FROM posts
GROUP BY Date
LIMIT 0, 25") or die(mysql_error());

//if we get any results we show them in table data
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0):

?>

<table id="lastTips" class="main" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th align="center">Date</th>
    <th align="center">Balance</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php 
  //while we going through each row we display info
  while($row=mysql_fetch_object($query)):?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row->Date;?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row->Balance;?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
//if we can't get results we show information
else: ?>
<h3>No Results found.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried several jquery functions without success, I have seen examples which call a separate file, but in my case I need to have the above code in the same file.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the code in the same file? When you make an ajax call, it should go to a file which only processes the request, and returns an object to the browser such as JSON.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Is there a way to put it in the same file? It won't work if I do it in a separate file. I'm using wordpress and to run the query by author page, it needs to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should split the code on two files. 
First "index.html" ( with html/js ):

<

```
script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn-week').click(function(){
  $.post("result.php", { date: "%U/%Y" }).done(function(data) 
    {
      formatResponse(data);
    }
  );
});
$('#btn-month').click(function(){
  $.post("result.php", { date: "%M/%Y" }).done(function(data) 
    {
      formatResponse(data);
    }
  );
});
function formatResponse( values ){
      var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//parse json response
      var element = $("#lastTips tbody");
      element.html('');//to clean previous result
      for ( var i in result ){  
        element.append('<tr><td align="center">' + values.date + '</td><td align="center">' + values.balance + '</td></tr>');//append to table
      }  
}
</script>

<input id="btn-week" style="width: auto" type="button" value="Weekly stats">
<input id="btn-month" style="width: auto" type="submit" value="Monthly Stats">    

<table id="lastTips" class="main" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th align="center">Date</th>
    <th align="center">Balance</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Second "result.php" with php:

```
<?php 

//execute a mysql query to retrieve all the users from users table
//if  query  fails stop further execution and show mysql error
if ($_POST['q'] == '') {
    $q = '%M/%Y';
}
else {
    $q = $_POST['q'] ;
}  
$query=mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((post_date), '".$q."') 'Date',
                    SUM(balance) 'Balance'
FROM posts
GROUP BY Date
LIMIT 0, 25") or die(mysql_error());

echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($query));
```

I doesn't have tested the code.
One warning, the html file cannot have two elements with same id ;)

Comment: I can't I'm using {global $post; $post_author = $post->post_author;} on wordpress to filter the table by author. If I separate the file, I can't get the author information. This file it's in the author-page and that's the only way to fetch the author's name. Hence I don't want to use json.

Comment: Ok, but you can send the author as param on ajax request, something like { date: "%U/%Y", author: <?php echo $post->post_author;?> }

Comment: is, it's possible, one way (uggly but work) it's put the php code on top of the file and check with " if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') " if it's ajax call and after process php response make a die(). Other options it's when you load page save all content on js var and the with js parse the content by filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AjaxForm](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) plug-in for jQuery:

```
$('.my-ajax-form').ajaxForm(function(data){
    alert(data);
    // do some thing with data here.
})
```

Comment: Thanks Rikky, I tried the Ajax form but couldn't make it work. Can you please provide more details on how to use it?

Comment: AjaxForm is very useful if you have to upload Images or files in general. IMHO simple $.ajax(); call in jQuery is enough http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Rikky, you didn't send any link to the sample

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have everything in the same file. In your example your calling ajax_server.php. Additionally, I don't want to echo text, it's just a button that changes the date format in a PHP mysql table, as shown in the code above. I tried Ajaxform and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't understand your goal clearly. If you want to extract data from db, just store it in a json object, then hide them. When user click a button, show them. Why ajax here?

Comment: @Rikky, this table dynamic and different for every author-page, hence I can't use a json file. I just want to use Ajax to call $_GET['q'].